# How to add custom seekbar in html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

i am working on webapp. In this webapp i want add a seek bar, volume, current time/total time,play/pause, and a timer (time should start when the video is playing and should pause, video is paused)
in this webapp i just want to calculate the total number to sec. video is played by user.
thank you in advance.

```
<html>
<body>
   <div style="text-align:center">
      <div id="video_player_box">
         <video id="my_video" width="550" height="300" onclick="playPause(this,'my_video')">
          <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4">
        </video>
        <div id="video_controls_bar">
          <button id="playpausebtn" onclick="playPause(this,'my_video')">Play</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <form id="watch">
      <p> TIME: <input type="text" id="txt" readonly></p>
      <p>COST: <input type="text" id="cost" readonly></p>
      As 0.9rs/sec
    </form>   

    <script>
      var str = "Hello World!";
      var result;
      var c = 0;
      var co = 0;
      var t;
      var timer_is_on = 0;

      function playPause(btn, vid) {
        var vid = document.getElementById(vid);
        if (vid.paused) {
          vid.play();
          btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
          result = str.fontcolor("green");
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
          if (!timer_is_on) {
            timer_is_on = 1;
            timedCount();
          }
        } else {
          result = str.fontcolor("red");
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
          vid.pause();
          btn.innerHTML = "Play";
          clearTimeout(t);
          timer_is_on = 0;
          myVideo.pause();    
        }
      }

      function timedCount() {
        document.getElementById('txt').value = c;
        document.getElementById('cost').value = co;
        c = c + 1;
        co = c * 0.9;
        t = setTimeout("timedCount()", 1000);
        if (vid.ended) {
          clearTimeout(t);
          timer_is_on = 0;
        }
      }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate Question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953604/html5-video-custom-additional-seek-bar/41953905