# HTML5 Video custom additional seek bar

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, canvas

I am tinkering around with HTML5 videos. I have a video working by using the vanilla HTML5 `<video>` tag, something like this:

```
<video id="video" width="250" height="250" controls>
    <source src="video_src.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

All is well. What I'm looking for is a way to have an additional seek bar at the bottom of the video. The seekbar will be an image I have that represents the video. By clicking anywhere on the image, the video will move to that point.

Again, this will work in addition to the default progress bar that comes with the default video functionality. The default and the custom seekbar would have to be in sync so that when one is updated, the other moves as well.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling to conceptualize it personally, but i can imagine you'd have to map a division of the total time of the video between the width of your seek bar, and clicking in a certain location would work out the difference in time currently and time allocated to that sector on your seek bar, and then add it to the video.

Comment: you're right @Crowes. I have implemented the same below.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
vid.ontimeupdate = function(){
  var percentage = ( vid.currentTime / vid.duration ) * 100;
  $("#custom-seekbar span").css("width", percentage+"%");
};

$("#custom-seekbar").on("click", function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var left = (e.pageX - offset.left);
    var totalWidth = $("#custom-seekbar").width();
    var percentage = ( left / totalWidth );
    var vidTime = vid.duration * percentage;
    vid.currentTime = vidTime;
});//click()
```

```css
#custom-seekbar
{  
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: thin solid orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
#custom-seekbar span
{
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0px;
}

/* following rule is for hiding Stack Overflow's console  */
.as-console-wrapper{ display: none !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-seekbar">
  <span></span>
</div>
<video id="video" width="400" controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: This is awesome. How would you go about clicking the top custom seekbar to then alter the location of the video? Right now, you can only really seek with the default bar.

Comment: @intl I have updated my answer to include that. Please note that this is a basic implementation and you may need to do some fine tuning.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot, this is very helpful.

Comment: @intl what if I don't want the seekbar of player. I want multiple bars like the second one and each having individual play button. Is it possible?

Comment: @ApurvG You mean you have multiple video sources? It would be helpful if you create a separate question for your problem if you could not find any question on SO similar to your problem. Thanks.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj, Great Work dude (y)

Comment: Thanks...  @AWE :)

Comment: How can you bind the "vid.ontimeupdate = function" to an ajax loaded video? tyring to but the width doesn't change at all

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign in that case, you just need to run all this after your video has been loaded.

Comment: Thanks for this. How bout if you want to use a Youtube video in the 'src' attribute?

Comment: @noogui for using YouTube video, you will need to use YouTube's API. So instead of calling html5 video methods, you would need to call YouTube API's methods.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj difficulty just escalated to Challenger level.

Comment: @noogui :D perhaps you can create a new question adding what you have tried