# Bind HTML5 video progress bar to AJAX loaded videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im opening up a video in a modal, with the video being loaded with $.get, and I can't bind the 'timeupdate' function for the seek bar to the video. I have tried numerous solutions, including the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953604/html5-video-custom-additional-seek-bar).

Here is the VideoFile.php contents:

```
<div id="video_container" class="l-rel l-twelve l-mb1">
    <video id="video_player" preload="auto" class="bdrRed" width="100%" poster="/Video/VisualizeTheMarkets.png">
        <source src="/Video/Vdeo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="/Video/Video.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <div id="video_controls">
        <div class="l-twelve l-nmb">
            <div id="custom-seekbar">
              <span></span>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div id="controlBar" class="l-twelve l-nmb l-pl1 l-pr1">
           <div class="flex-1 flex-c">
               <button type="button" id="play-pause" class="play">Play</button>
               <button type="button" id="mute" class="mute">Mute</button>
               <input type="range" id="volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1"> 
               <button type="button" id="full-screen">Full-Screen</button>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how I load the video:
HTML

```
<a data-href="/AJAX/Video/VideoFile.php" href="#" class="vidpop">See How</a>
```

Video JS call

```
$('.vidpop').click(function(e){
    var link = $(this).data('href');
    $.get(link, function(data){
        modal.open({content: data, "width":"700px"});
    }).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        $('<svg id="video-play-button" class="video-overlay-play-button" viewBox="0 0 200 200" alt="Play video"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" fill="none" stroke-width="15" stroke="#fff"/><polygon points="70, 55 70, 145 145, 100" fill="#fff"/></svg>').appendTo($('#video_container'));
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And finally, trying to make the 'custom-seekbar > span' increase width on timeupdate:

```
$(document).on('timeupdate', '#video_player', function(){
    var currentPos = $('#video_player')[0].currentTime;
    var maxduration = $('#video_player')[0].duration;
    var percentage = 100 * currentPos / maxduration; //in %
    console.log(currentPos, maxduration, percentage);
});
    var vid = document.getElementById("video_player");
    vid.ontimeupdate = function(){
    var percentage = ( vid.currentTime / vid.duration ) * 100;
    $("#custom-seekbar span").css("width", percentage+"%");
};

$(document).on('timeupdate', '#custom-seekbar span', function(){
     $("#custom-seekbar span").css("width", percentage+"%");
});
```

The "custom-seekbar span" doesn't change width. How do you bind the function to an element that doesn't exist on the page yet?

Comment: #`the 'custom-seekbar span' doesn't chagne width`# should be caused by missing `display:inline-block`, so change it to `<span style="background-color:gray;display:inline-block;">Progress...</span>` then try again.

Comment: I get this in console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ontimeupdate' of null at videoA.js:86" I can't seem to bind "ontimeupdate" to the video

Comment: I tried your codes, it succeeded to bind ontimeupdate for document.getElementById("video_player"). May I know what does videoA.js do?

Comment: videoA.js has other button functionality that works to this point. The part of it in the code above is the part of my question "And finally, trying to make the 'custom-seekbar > span..." section

Comment: how did you get it to bind?

Comment: I get console error "videoA.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null" since it hasn't been loaded and the code is running on doc ready. That is the issue I have, I can't bind it when the video is laoded.

Comment: FINALLY!!! I had to use the ".done" implementation of Promise on the $.get to run the function